# Calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}{1.5}^i}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Given the sequence $\displaystyle{S_n}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}{1.5}^i}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}1}$

How can I calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ (or prove the divergence of this sequence)?

I believe that it can be achieved by analyzing $S_n-S_{n-1}$, but I'm not quite sure how.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the closed formula for geometric sums?

Comment: @DanielFischer: What if I do?

Comment: Use it to get an expression for $S_n$ where the behaviour is easier to see.

Comment: Although, a simple estimate would be enough here.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh, I see. Something like $S_n=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$ (if it was $2$ instead of $1.5$ up there).

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks. I apologize for the stupid question; Will be removed shortly :)

Comment: As for using a simple estimate, note $S_n> 1.5^n/(n+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

One of the possibilities: apply the AGM inequality to show that
$$S_n\geq \left(1.5^{0+1+\ldots+n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}=1.5^{\frac{n}{2}}.$$

Comment: Hence the sequence diverges... right?

Comment: @barakmanos Yes. Alternatively you can apply the method from the comments and use that $1.5^n$ grows faster than $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $$\sum_{i=0}^n x^i = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$ then $S_n$ can be written as $$S_n = \frac1n\frac{(3/2)^n-1}{3/2-1}$$

Now we see that $S_n$ is ratio of a function that is going to $\infty$ exponentially and a function that is going to $\infty$ linearly. Therefore $S_n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

$P_n=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n}1.5^i=\dfrac{1-1.5^n}{1-1.5}=-2+2\cdot1.5^n.$ See [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

$Q_n=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n}1=n-0+1=n+1.$

So: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{P_n}{Q_n}=\infty.$ Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\exp(n)}{n}=\infty$.